# how to get the most common character in an array?

Tags: java

Suppose I have an integer array like this:
{5,3,5,4,2}

and I have a method which returns the most common character

```
public int highestnumber(String[] num) {

        int current_number = Integer.parseInt(num[0]);
        int counter = 0;
        for (int i = 1; i < num.length; ++i) {
            if (current_number == Integer.parseInt(num[i])) {
                ++counter;

            } else if (counter == 0) {
                current_number = Integer.parseInt(num[i]);
                ++counter;

            } else {
                --counter;

            }
        }

        return current_number;
    }
```

but if I have multiple common character then i need to get the number which is closest to one(1), like if i have an array like this:
{5,5,4,4,2};

then the method should return 4, what should I do for this?

Comment: if your array is like this {5,4,5,5,4,2,2,5} then which number you want? and one more question why you are passing string array ? it could be integer array no? you want common character or common numbers?

Comment: In this condition I get 5, and its correct, but I am facing problem only when the  most common characters are multiple. Like if i have 5 three times and 4 three times in an array then i should get 4 because it is closest to 1. And for my coding I had to pass string array, its not a big deal

Comment: This has nothing to do with android. It's not always relevant to add in which context you're using the code.

Comment: Look at my edited answer, Complete answer for your question :-)

Comment: I have unswered in your post, plz check

Comment: I have try with your newly array and it returns me 2..

Comment: Can you post your code what have you written?

Comment: @Reyjohn: You don't need to make manual notifications about submitting an answer - the system is doing it itself.

Comment: You can count Strings too - no need to convert them always on the fly to int. If you would convert them, that would be fine, but do it just once! And rename the method, *highestnumber* is something else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per what I understand your question,

What you have to done is,

```
1. Create ArrayList from your int[]
2. Use HashMap for find duplicates, which one is unique
3. Sort it as Ascending order, 
4. First element is what you want..
```

**EDIT: Answer for your question**

```
int[] arr = {5, 4, 5, 4, 2};
ArrayList<Integer> resultArray = new ArrayList<Integer>();
Set<Integer> set = new HashSet<Integer>();

for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
    {
     if (set.contains(arr[i]))
    {
     System.out.println("Duplicate value found at index: " + i);
     System.out.println("Duplicate value: " + arr[i]);
         resultArray.add(arr[i]);
    }
    else
    {
    set.add(arr[i]);
    }
   }
Collections.sort(resultArray);

for (int i = 0; i < resultArray.size(); i++)
{
Log.e("Duplicate Values:", resultArray.get(i) + "");
}
```

Your need is,

```
int values = resultArray.get(0);
```

Comment: I think you didnt get my question correctly. I am getting the most common character from my own method, and I am ok with it. But i am facing problem when the answer is multiple, like if I have two number appear same time in that array then it should return the minimum one

Comment: Add all most common character from your method in ArrayList and just sort it as ascending order.

Comment: I am trying, I will let you know?

Comment: Look at my edited answer, Complete answer for your question :-)

Comment: Ok I am trying it :) Thanks for your effort

Comment: When the array is {0,3,3,2,2}; this returns 3, but I need 2 because this is the smalest one

Comment: impossible, the same thing works with your newly array {0,3,3,2,2}; and it returns me 2. This line is important.. Collections.sort(resultArray); before you getting value from resultArray.get(0)

Answer (score 2):

Sort the array then count runs of values.

Answer (score 1):

Fast way.
Create a counter int array one element for each number. Go through the array once and increment corresponding counter array for each number. Set highest number to first counter element then go through and change highest number to current element only if it is bigger than highest number, return highest number.

```
public int highestNumber(String[] num){
    int[] count = new int[10];
    int highest_number = 0;
    int highest_value = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < num.length; i++)
        count[Integer.parseInt(num[i])]++;;

    for(int i = 0; i < count.length; i++)
        if(count[i] > highest_value){
            highest_number = i;
            highest_value = count[i];
        }

    return highest_number;
}
```

10x slower but without other array.
Create three ints one for number and two for counting. Go through the array once for each int and increment current counting each time it shows up, if bigger that highest count, set to highest count and set highest number to current count. Return highest number.

```
public int highestNumber(String[] num){
    int highest_number = 0;
    int highest_value = 0;
    int current_value = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < num.length; j++)
            if(i == Integer.parseInt(num[j]))
                current_value++;

        if(current_value > highest_value){
            highest_value = current_value;
            highest_number = i;
        }

        current_value = 0;
    }

    return highest_number;
}
```

The first is obviously much faster but if for whatever reason you don't want another array the second one works too.

Answer (score 1):

You can also try this:

```
import java.util.TreeMap;

public class SmallestFrequentNumberFinder {

    public static int[] stringToIntegerArray(String[] stringArray) {
        int[] integerArray = new int[stringArray.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < stringArray.length; i++) {
            integerArray[i] = Integer.parseInt(stringArray[i]);
        }
        return integerArray;
    }

    public static int getSmallestFrequentNumber(int[] numbers) {
        int max = -1;
        Integer smallestFrequentNumber = null;
        TreeMap<Integer, Integer> frequencyMaper = new TreeMap<Integer, Integer>();

        for (int number : numbers) {
            Integer frequency = frequencyMaper.get(number);
            frequencyMaper.put(number, (frequency == null) ? 1 : frequency + 1);
        }

        for (int number : frequencyMaper.keySet()) {
            Integer frequency = frequencyMaper.get(number);
            if (frequency != null && frequency > max) {
                max = frequency;
                smallestFrequentNumber = number;
            }
        }
        return smallestFrequentNumber;
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        String[] numbersAsString = {"5", "5", "4", "2", "4", "4", "2", "2"};
        final int[] integerArray = stringToIntegerArray(numbersAsString);
        System.out.println(getSmallestFrequentNumber(integerArray));
    }
}
```